# Checking inside of the div tag with innerhtml in javascript?

Tags: php, html, javascript, ajax, dom

im trying to make a registration form with ajax validation check.
validation check is OK. i make it show a cross.png image when there is a problem about a field on the form.

but what i wanna do next is to not let visitors apply the registration form when there is problem.

i tried to check for errors by

```
if(document.getElementById('username_error_icon').innerHTML!='<img src="cross.png" width="15" height="15" />'){
document.form1.submit();    
}
```

which didnt work :/
im open to suggestion
please help :/

Comment: This should really be asked on Stack Overflow, not SU, as it is a programming question. You should find that the community or a moderator migrates the question there for you shortly.

Comment: Could you do an alert(document.getElementById('username_error_icon').innerHTML) and let us know what it shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact innerHTML value of an element isn't something that is constant accross all browser. You shouldn't rely on it. Some browser re-order the attribute order, rewrite the path of the "src".

You should do something along that :

```
function isValid() {
    // Do your test and return true/false
}

// ...

function functionWhereYourCodeIs() {
    if (isValid()) {
        document.form1.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: but the problem is valid function which also adds 
<img src="cross.png" width="15" height="15" />
onto page is in php code which is called with ajax method.
so i dont know how to send both image html code and validation value from one php code

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to validate something like this, comparing two strings which can change.

Instead, I recommend you setting a variable like `bErrOccurred = true` where you set the source of the image to cross.png and then your if statement should look like the following:

```
if(!bErrOccurred) {
    document.form1.submit();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in case you still want to do it, you can do this

```
    <div id="username_error_icon">
        <img id="myValidationImage" src="cross.png" width="15" height="15" />
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var validationImage = document.getElementById('myValidationImage').src;
    var imageName = validationImage.lastIndexOf('.');
    validationImage = validationImage.substring(validationImage.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imageName < 0 ? validationImage.length : imageName);
    if (validationImage != "cross")
        document.form1.submit();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok as it seems i'll need to change the whole ajax code to only get validation result as a variable from php without any html tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

ok problem solved.
by changing php code that returns information to ajax code.
i changed php code to return validation result without any html tag but with 0 or 1 or 2 etc.
and then changed javascript code to do proper changes in html dedicated to these returned values